# partitioning tree nodes with clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

I have an undirected tree structure where each edge has length associated. Given a random selection of nodes, I need to partition them into subsets S1, S2, ..., Sk (all may be equal or close in size) such that the path length between any two nodes within a subset is <= those in two different subsets.
My understanding is that this is not a standard graph partitioning problem.

To me it seemed closest to k-means algorithm, but that does not take arbitrary distance measures.
Googling around, I found that *k-medoid* algorithm allows arbitrary distance metric, which looks promising. I am thinking of creating pairwise distance matrix (D[i,j] = path length from node i to node j) and putting that into a k-medoid algorithm. Is that a reasonable approach or are there standard algorithms that I am missing?

Comment: If you randomly select some of the nodes of your tree, the nodes might not be connected anymore. Do you want the distance between two nodes to be the distance in the underlying tree? In general it seems to me that you can utilize the tree structure for the clustering, e.g., search k disjoint subtrees with roughly equal size.

Comment: @SaiBot Exactly. Thanks for the pointer.